# is it better to name the subclass's mocked class same with subclass but in different .h in c++?

Tags: c++, mocking, filenames, naming

I have parent class:

```
BaseClass;
```

and it's sub class is `SubClass`,

when I need one mocked subclass for the subclass, how to name it?

I check someone's code sample, the subclass's mock class and itself use same name, but in different .h file, one is subclass.h.the other's is mocksubclass.h,

so in this case, is there need to name the mock subclass to use one different name such as : `MockSubClass`?

Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to name the subclass's mock class the same as the subclass. Perhaps you meant the mock class is mocking the base class? But then that's not the same as what you're asking.

Comment: I check the code. in actual, the subclass's mock class's name is same, I'am not sure if it is a good practice, so I ask this question!

Comment: Is the mock class in another namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your needs. The approach you mention is reasonable, i.e. CMyClass->CMockMyClass. Generally you will have a mock class per subclass, and there are times when you need to mock the base class as well. Using 'interface' classes can help when creating the mock classes, as per [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576568/mock-implementations-in-c) What mocking framework are you using? Are they true mocks or just stubs?

Comment: what time I  can use same name for mock class?